# Dialogflow integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

I am using Dialogflow Essentials and i already have english language working fine in google action and google assistant. Now i am trying to integrate french-Ca from dialog flow to google action console,
i am not able to see french-Ca in google action console. When i go to the google action console , i can see 12 Actions in english but none in french-Ca. I did these steps: Integrations-Continue with integration, and close.(All the intents are marked). Also tried Add action from google action console but couldn't make it happen. Can someone please assist me with that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the languages supported in your Action from your project's settings in the Actions Console.

Example URL: https://console.actions.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/languages

You can select French and add the Canada locale using the 'Add locale' button.